# How to keep only one of consecutive repeating elements in a row matrix and represent the result by figure?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

Given the matrix

```
A=[1 3 3 2 2 4 4 1]
```

I want this output: `[1 3 2 4 1]`

Further more, I want to make a figure like this:

[image]

Arrow heads points from 1st columnn of A to 2nd column of A then from 3rd column to 4th column and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question:

```
A(diff(A)~=0)
```

Regarding your second question, you can use [digraph](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html).

Comment: I think you're missing the first index. Maybe `A(diff([Inf A])~=0)`?